# How to separate web Elements from Page Object file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

So I am following the page object model and have a class(Class A) that has elements and functions for a specific page. I also have a Test test class that uses Class A. currently I have at least 222 Web Elements for the Page because the page has many components to fill out for regression testing. As you can imagine, the Page object has hundreds of lines of code with just web elements at the top and the functions at the bottom. I want to know how I can seperate these web elements so that the code can be cleaner.

I've seen articles from guru99 on how you can put it in and XML but the way its being done in the article doesn't solve my issue because i would still need to initialize them some how or have 'driver.find(locator from XML)' everywhere and so the code would still be messy.

Page Object Class A

```
    public class PageA extends BasePage{

      @FindBy(xpath="//*[some xpath]")
      WebElement inputField1
      @FindBy(xpath="//*[some xpath]")
      WebElement inputField2
      @FindBy(xpath="//*[some xpath]")
      WebElement inputField3


     public PageA(Webdriver driver){
       super(driver);
     }

      public void method1(){
        //do something
      }

    }
```

I want to be able to initialize the 222 Web Elements some where else so that code is cleaner

Comment: Do all the 222 web elements belongs to the single page of application? If not (which most probably won't be the case) having those in 1 class defeats the whole purpose of page object model.

Comment: yes all 222 elements belong to the single page

Answer (score 0):

The much better idea will be to create your own elements like **Button**, **Link**, **Input**, etc.

Instead of general `WebElement`. It isn't so comfortable to work with so general web element API. You have a possibility to type text (send keys) to button or to link.

1. More information about it: [How to implement user types for @FindBy annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478592/how-to-implement-user-types-for-findby-annotation)
   .
2. You could use existing library with such functional, like [Html Elements framework](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements)
3. you could use a framework with Page Object concept, like [Selenide](https://selenide.org/documentation/page-objects.html) or [Serenity framework](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/page-objects.html)